# How to search for a missing property in a Delphi DFM component declaration?

Tags: regex, dfm

I'm trying to get all occurrencies of the `TcxRadioGroup` class which have not a value for the `Caption` property in Delphi DFM files.

I have to do this in a big groupproject with thousands of forms. For this reason I'm looking for a solution which can work on multiple files (I thought to use a *RegEx* in *Notepad++* but I'm open to any other solution)

**Example:**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 494
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object cxRadioGroup1: TcxRadioGroup
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Align = alTop
    Caption = 'cxRadioGroup1'
    Properties.Items = <>
    TabOrder = 0
    ExplicitLeft = 24
    ExplicitTop = 16
    ExplicitWidth = 185
    Height = 105
    Width = 635
  end
  object cxRadioGroup2: TcxRadioGroup
    Left = 0
    Top = 389
    Align = alBottom
    Properties.Items = <>
    TabOrder = 1
    ExplicitTop = 293
    Height = 105
    Width = 635
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 200
    Top = 111
    Width = 257
    Height = 265
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 2
    object cxRadioGroup3: TcxRadioGroup
      Left = 8
      Top = 16
      Caption = 'cxRadioGroup3'
      Properties.Items = <>
      TabOrder = 0
      Height = 105
      Width = 185
    end
    object cxRadioGroup4: TcxRadioGroup
      Left = 8
      Top = 144
      Properties.Items = <
        item
          Caption = 'item 1'
        end
        item
          Caption = 'item 2'
        end>
      TabOrder = 1
      Height = 105
      Width = 185
    end
  end
end
```

In this example, I'm expecting to find `cxRadioGroup2` and `cxRadioGroup4` components.

---

**1° Attempt:**

I've tried to use a regular expression but I don't know how to find occurences which have not the `Caption` line... Using Notepad++, I've started by trying to catch each `TcxRadioGroup` block until their `end` line (the `end` line which has the same indentation).

`^\s*object\s(\w*):\sTcxRadioGroup.*end`
with options `/gms`

It catches from `object cxRadioGroup1` to the last `end` of the file

---

**2° Attempt:**

I've used [lazy matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) and [reused the captured white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318955/reuse-matched-group-in-regex/) in order to match the right `end` for each component declaration.

`^(\s*)object\s(\w*):\sTcxRadioGroup.*?\n\1end` with options `/gms`

It finds all `TcxRadioGroup` declarations, each one from its beginning to its end. I think I should find a way to exclude the ones who contains `\1  Caption =`

I've prepared an [online example](https://regex101.com/r/xv7U8g/2).

Comment: Could downvoters explain?

Comment: This is a typical use case for the Missing Property Report of Pascal Analyzer: https://www.peganza.com/PALHelp/missing_property_report.htm

Comment: RegEx is not a magic bullet... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @KenBourassa But in this instance, a regex based script can do the job

Comment: @Fabrizio This is really a regex question and at least for now I have closed it as such. Really what you are looking for is to use lazy rather than greedy matching. Realistically, Notepad++ isn't really the right tool for working with large numbers of files. You need to write some code to look in all your files. Delphi is also the wrong tool. You should look for a scripting language. I would also reach for Python at this point.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I've edited and re-tagged the question, leaving regex and dfm tags only

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Could you please explain why this question is duplicated of [What do 'lazy' and 'greedy' mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions). If it was, its solution should solve my question too

Comment: The question was "It catches from object cxRadioGroup1 to the last end of the file". And that's because of the lazy vs greedy issue. Once you know how to solve that, you can write code to do the rest surely.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The question is (and was) how to find the `TcxRadioGroup` objects which have not the `Caption` property. You're confusing the doubts I had while attempting to solve the question by myself, with the question itself

Comment: Walk through each line of your dfm files. When you match `object .*: TcxRadioGroup` make a note of the indentation level. Read the following lines and see if you get a `Caption` property with indentation two spaces more. When you reach an `end` with the same indentation as the original `object` then you are done. This won't handle dfm inheritance.  But you probably won't have many instances of that so they can be done manually. Use a language like Python to write this code.